# Why does bc exit 0 when dividing by 0?

Tags: command-line, posix, bc

I was trying to think of a quick and illustrative way to generate a non-successful exit status and thought dividing by zero with the [`bc`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bc&sektion=1) would be a good idea.

I was suprised to discover that although it does generate a runtime error, the exit status is still 0:

```
$ echo 41 + 1 | bc
42
$ echo $?
0
$ echo 42/0 | bc
Runtime error (func=(main), adr=6): Divide by zero
$ echo $?
0
```

- Why does the bc utility not fail with a non-zero exit status?

Note: For a quick non-zero exit status I'm using `return 1`

Also, from [shell-tips](https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/):

```
$ expr 1 / 0
expr: division by zero
$ echo $?
2
```

Comment: I would use `ls nosuchfile` for the illustration, by the way.  Or if I want to show how non-zero exit statuses *do* have conventional meanings, I would set up as follows: `echo hello > file1; echo hello > file2; echo goodbye > file3` and then show the exit status for `cmp file1 file2`, `cmp file1 file3`, `cmp file1 file4`.

Comment: You cannot devide by 0? The answer is unlimited?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bc` implementations differ a bit in their return status, but the general idea is that if you supply valid input then `bc` exits with the status 0. `42/0` is valid input: there's no read error, and it's even a syntactically valid expression, so `bc` returns 0. If you passed a second line with another operation, `bc` would perform it. This is different from `expr` whose purpose is to evaluate a single arithmetic expression; here the outcome of that single expression determines the return status.

The most straightforward way to generate an exit status that indicates failure is to call `false`. Things like `expr 1 / 0` only have their place in obfuscated programming contests.

Answer (score 6):

Look in the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html#tag_20_09_14); this is expected behavior.

All of the input was read correctly by `bc`, so it produced exit status 0.

If you run `bc` on a non-existent file, like `bc nosuchfile`, you will get some other exit status.

---

For illustrating a non-zero exit status, I would either compare `ls somefile` and `ls nosuchfile`, or I would show how exit statuses 1 and 2 are conventionally used (1 for expected error or failure status, 2 for unexpected error) like so:

```
$ echo hello > file1
$ echo hello > file2
$ echo goodbye > file3
$ cmp -s file1 file2
$ echo $?
0
$ cmp -s file1 file3
$ echo $?
1
$ cmp -s file1 file4
$ echo $?
2
$
```

Comment: Also note: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/bc.html#tag_20_09_16

Comment: @user367890, yes, thanks.  I considered adding that to the answer but decided against it, since ultimately it just says, "The reasons are historical."  But I will comment that POSIX formalizes what is already standard in practice: requiring behavior different from that of all existing implementations isn't the goal, even if it that behavior might seem like a better design.  So "historical reasons" actually describes much of POSIX.

Comment: It is _accepted_ behaviour, but not _mandated_ nor recommended (so I wouldn't put _expected_ here). The exit status is unspecified if there's an error. Here, regardless of POSIX conformance, in the case of GNU bc, I'd argue it's a bug as upon that division by zero (but also upon syntax error), it's a fatal error, `bc` doesn't process further input.

Comment: @Wildcard: Yes, but a non zero exit code does not indicate there was a failure reading – it could, but an implementation could also exit with `<> 0` on for example `n / 0`. As the Q is *“Why does bc exit 0 when dividing by 0?”* – one should likely point out that this is an invalid statement. From how I read it, even failure to read input file could also result in exit code 0 as it is *unspecified*. Perhaps I am wrong.